# Where do I find these kind of elements and what is the font used?

Tags: logo, font-identification

My question is where I can find logo elements like the one above with similar colors? Also, what is the font used?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo elements are called elipses. Standard shape in most any illustrator software. Cloned, rotated, and color added with transparency.

Granted, you don't want to make a logo that looks like that, as that logo obviously already exists.

The typeface appears to be a tightly tracked FontFont Olsen:

https://www.fontfont.com/fonts/olsen/regular

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to find logo elements ;) you can create your own logo elements like that yourself using Adobe Illustrator or a simmilar software. This way you'll end up with something more closer to unique, not borrowed and seen in another 10 places.

For stuff like in your example I would use scripts for Illustrator, like **[fleurify](http://www.limonova.com/www/illustrator/1002-fleurify.html)** and **fractalize** both created by John Wundes(both work with CS5). Have a look at the scripts [on his website](http://www.wundes.com/JS4AI/index.php)... I have lots of fun with them. You'll find instructions on how to install them. Its easy! Just copy them into the Presets/Scripts folder in Illustrator and then you'll find them under File > Scripts. (ask if you need more instructions).